# Possible to get element without actual visiting the url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

I don't know much about web development and newly jumped into `React Native` development. Hence my question might seems to be very basic to you.

A url as `https://youtube7.download/mini.php?id=JM6D6ZY8G50` is just to have a button with href link `https://t2.youtube7.download/ebr/afb53284003e198ab8ed4301e525f1dee690aa70/JM6D6ZY8G50`

Is it possible to grab the second link without actual visiting the first link in browser, or in anyway silent visiting?

Comment: I don't think so. The characters in the 2nd url don't seem in any way derived from the first one.

Comment: @bigblind: I think simply by visiting the url, the html page rendered will return a link as such, thought can visiting it silently without opening browser in any way